# Error Binding to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that queries CRM 2011 and then binds the results to a DropDownList, this is my code:

```
    public void CheckRsmPopulateAccounts()
    {

            string rsmFirstName = _currentUser.FirstName;
            string rsmLastName = _currentUser.LastName;

            ddlCustomer.DataSource = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                             join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals c["accountid"]
                             join u in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals u["systemuserid"]
                             where u["firstname"].Equals(rsmFirstName) && u["lastname"].Equals(rsmLastName)
                             select new
                             {
                                 AccountId = !r.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : r["accountid"],
                                 Account = !c.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : r["name"]
                             });

            ddlCustomer.DataValueField = "AccountId";
            ddlCustomer.DataTextField = "Account";
            ddlCustomer.DataBind();


    }
```

But for some reason it keeps giving me a `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` error, on it looks like the `DataBind` command. I can't seem to figure out the issue, the error seems so generic. Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `TargetInvocationException` will typically have an inner exception that indicates what the actual problem is. Post the full details of the exception, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select new {}` creates an anonymous type. You cannot enumerate through an anonymous typed object.

add `.ToList()` at the end of your linq

check also that your Linq is actually returning something  and make sure that you don't have any columns that comes back `null`

Comment: Thanks, Looks like it is returning NULL, is there a good way to handle that?

Comment: you should assign the linq query result to a variable and check it